# Deriving the joint posterior pdf as a decomposition in terms of...

Tags: statistics, bayesian, bayes-theorem, time-series

Really struggling with how to approach this question. The lecturer, as per usual, has provided us with the bare minimum in terms of hints on how to approach this. I know how to do it when we want in terms of the conditional pdf for $\mu$ given $\sigma$ and the data and the marginal pdf for $\sigma$ given the data, by expressing and expanding the exponent in the normal pdf via the inclusion of $\bar{y}$, but I have no idea how to manipulate this to get it the way she wants. Anyway, any help or advice you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

$y_i$ are distributed i.i.d normal($\mu, \sigma^2$)

Assuming a non-informative prior

p($\mu,\sigma)=1/\sigma$,

and given

p($\mu,\sigma$|**y**)$\propto$L($\mu,\sigma$|**y**) p($\mu,\sigma$),

re-specify the joint pdf, p($\mu,\sigma$|**y**) as the following decomposition:

p($\mu,\sigma$|**y**)= p($\sigma|\mu$, **y**) p($\mu$|**y**),

providing the complete forms of p($\sigma|\mu$, **y**) and p($\mu$|**y**) in the answer.

Thanks guys

Comment: Here's a [tutorial and reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) on how to typeset math on this site.

Comment: Is there any chance you can show me the complete form of p($\sigma|\mu$, y)?

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$p(\mu,\sigma)=\frac1\sigma\;,$$

$$L(\mu,\sigma\mid\mathbf y)=\prod_i\frac{\mathrm e^{-\frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}=\frac{\mathrm e^{-\frac{\Sigma_i(y_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sigma^n(2\pi)^{\frac n2}}$$

and thus

$$p(\mu,\sigma\mid\mathbf y)=\frac1\sigma\prod_i\frac{\mathrm e^{-\frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}=\frac{\mathrm e^{-\frac{\Sigma_i(y_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sigma^{n+1}(2\pi)^{\frac n2}}\;.
$$

The marginal distribution $p(\mu\mid\mathbf y)$ is obtained by integrating over $\sigma$. With

$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm e^{-a/\sigma^2}}{\sigma^{n+1}}\mathrm d\sigma=\frac12\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-ax}x^{\frac n2-1}\mathrm dx=\frac12a^{-\frac n2}\Gamma\left(\frac n2\right)\;,
$$

the result is

$$
p(\mu\mid\mathbf y)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac n2\right)}{2\left(\pi\Sigma_i(y_i-\mu)^2\right)^{\frac n2}}\;.
$$

Then $p(\sigma\mid\mu,\mathbf y)$ follows from

$$
p(\mu,\sigma\mid\mathbf y)=p(\sigma\mid\mu,\mathbf y)p(\mu\mid\mathbf y)\;.
$$

Comment: is there any chance of showing me the complete form of p(σ∣μ,y)? Would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Jan: What's left to show? You just need to solve the last equation for $p(\sigma\mid\mu,\mathbf y)$; I gave explicit expressions for the other two quantities that appear in that equation.